# Simple web page

Tags: php, html

I am a novice with html and PHP, but I have a fairly simple requirement.  I have tried a number of different approaches, but none of them meet my needs.

The page should do the following:

1. Display some text, a picture, and the date-timestamp of a file from
   the server (this works Display a button.
2. If the user clicks the
   button, perform php that modifies files on the server. (This works, but see problem below)
3. Refresh the page every 30 seconds (to display effects of a server process that updates the
   picture and date-timestamp mentioned in 1 above).

Following is what I am currently trying in g_test_02.php.  The problem is that when I load the page in a browser, *when it refreshes from the header, it performs the  even though I have not clicked the button.*  I can see this viewing the files on the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH"
CONTENT="30">
</head>

<?PHP
Do some php to display the date-timestamp of a file on the Unix server
?>

Display some html text and a picture

<script>
function myFunction() {
<?php
Do some php to modify files on the server
?>
        location.reload();
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Verify door</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would be because `PHP` is **server side** and runs before the `HTML/CSS/JS` as that's **client side**. You'll need to look at using ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")}, 5000);
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Verify door</button>

</body>
</html>
```